# List all elements of array

Tags: c#, arrays, lambda

I know this is a real low level question (I'm a beginner), but I got to know...
what is the best way to list all elements of an array?
I'm a little anal and always want to write the best code. I know we can write a function and pass the array and access every element using a for or foreach. but I have heard there is a better way for doing this. (something about lambda expressions)
Do you know how to do that?

Comment: `System.Linq` gives you all kinds of options depending on what you want to do, but at the end of the day it's all just syntactical sugar for a `for`, `while` or `do while` loop. Keep it simple and readable.

Comment: Could you provide *relevant code*, please? Hardly can one answer "what is the best way to do something" in *general* case.

Comment: I guarantee there is a `for` or `foreach` somewhere down the line, whether it be a linq statement or some other rendition.  Sometimes the simplest solution is the one easiest to read.

Comment: *I[...] always want to write the best code*. That's a mindset you need to break. There's no such thing as "the best" code or "the best" solution to any problem. The best code is code that is maintainable, makes its intent clear, and works properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, there is a function for iterating through and array.
The concept of lambda expressions is a little advanced, so I don't recommend learning it right now.(since you're a beginner)
but you can use this syntax. It's easy to use and handy:

```
static void Main(string[] args)    
{    
    int[] someArray = { 1, 2, 3, 69, 4 };    
    Array.ForEach(someArray, element => Console.WriteLine(element));    
}
```